# Does POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED remove dirty pages from other processes on Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I've been doing some research on madvise.

Example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg6-LVCHmGM&feature=youtu.be&t=1h13m24s

[Does madvise(___, ___, MADV_DONTNEED) instruct the OS to lazily write to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968309/does-madvise-madv-dontneed-instruct-the-os-to-lazily-write-to-disk)

This indicates that the dirty pages will not be written to disk if madvise is called.

Is the behavior of posix_fadvise the same when called with POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED?

If the behavior is the same, what happens when posix_fadvise is called for a file that is opened in two separate files?

Do the dirty pages on the other process get evicted without being written to disk?

Comment: Remember that `madvice`/`fadvice` are merely *hints* to the kernel - it's not obligated to actually *do* anything if it doesn't feel like it.

Comment: The kernel does respond to the advise, so the question is what is the behavior of the kernel to the advise.

Answer (score 0):

No. Everything about Linux `MADV_DONTNEED` is contrary to POSIX semantics and not usable for implementation of `posix_madvise` or `posix_fadvise`. It's only relevant if you call the non-standardized `madvise` function.